# Firebase secure way of detecting user presence

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have an app that deals with WebRTC. I plan to use Firebase RTDB for signaling and administrate user connections to rooms.

I was looking at how to manage user presence to disconnect the user from a room automatically when he/she closes the browser. From the docs, it seems that the only way to do it is through the client side:

```
firebase.database().ref('.info/connected').on('value', function(snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.val() == false) {
        return;
    };
    userStatusDatabaseRef.onDisconnect().set(isOfflineForDatabase).then(function() {
        userStatusDatabaseRef.set(isOnlineForDatabase);
    });
});
```

Although this works in normal cases, what if there's a malicious user that rewrites the code to do just this instead:

```
userStatusDatabaseRef.set(isOnlineForDatabase);
```

From what I see here, this would make the user permanently online whether he disconnects or not.

And from another perspective, it seems this way of doing things violates the principle of "never trust the client".

Is there something I'm missing here? Or maybe a workaround? Maybe a function that triggers when a user listens to '.info/connected'?

Would love to hear your input on this.